# Xbox won't turn on after flashing

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, xbox-dashboard

My Xbox was working properly but I had the older dashboard in my Xbox 360 E jtag. I installed the latest dashboard using Simple 360 Nand Flasher. As it reflashed, it turned the console off and now its not opening.

When I press on the console button the green light pops up and I can also eject the disc tray and the power adapter is also perfectly fine plus the HDMI is fully plugged in and properly working. When I press the xbox start button the green light pops up as usual but it doesn't boot up nor does it make any sound.

I have tried to start it multiple times but it isn't working
On the TV it just says No Signal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of this matter may not really be the Xbox itself, it could be the wall socket the Xbox is connected to. If it's not so, then the video cable of the console has to be inspected to ensure it is put in place. If the video cable is fine, then you can reset the internal power supply.
Follow these steps:

- Unplug the power cord from the console.
- Wait 10 seconds.
- Plug the cord back into the console
- Press the Xbox button on the front of the console.

If this did not help, then go ahead and visit http://support.xbox.com for any help.